# Solving the equation $16c^2=a^2+15b^2$ over integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I solve the following diophantine equation ?

> $$16c^2=a^2+15b^2$$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ .

---

We are not interested in the trivial cases $a=b=c$
or $b=0$ .

$\rm {Attempts :}$ ( Left for the Original Poster )

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $(60m^2-4, 8m, 15m^2+1)$ is a solution.

Comment: @BobDobbs I generalized the solution set .

Comment: @skylake Please add your *attempts*  that you have tried in the $\rm{Attempts :}$ I added to your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This answer can be deleted by voting if the question asked does not improve in the future .</sub>

---

Let $\thinspace b≠0\thinspace$, then you have :

$$
\begin{align}16c^2&=a^2+15b^2\\
16\left(\frac cb\right)^2&=\left(\frac ab \right)^2+15\end{align}
$$

Actually, it is enough to solve the equation for $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z_{≥0}$ .  But, we will go to the solution without this restriction .

Let $\thinspace m=\dfrac cb\thinspace $ and $\thinspace n=\dfrac ab\thinspace $, then we can write the following :

$$
\begin{align}&(4m-n)(4m+n)=15\\\\
\implies &\begin{cases} 4m-n=k,\thinspace k\in\mathbb Q_{≠\thinspace 0}\\
4m+n=\dfrac {15}{k}\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\begin{cases}m=\dfrac {k^2+15}{8k}\\
n=\dfrac{15-k^2}{2k}\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Let $\thinspace k=\dfrac pq$, where $(p,q)\in\mathbb Z^{2}$ with $q≠0$, then we get :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{m=\frac {p^2+15 q^2}{8pq}, \thinspace\thinspace n=\frac {4(15 q^2-p^2)}{8pq}}\end{align}
$$

Finally, recall that you can always write $m$ and $n$ in the common denominator. One possible general *explicit* solution family can be constructed as follows :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\begin{align}a&=4r(15q^2-p^2)\\ b&=8pqr\\
c&=r(p^2+15q^2)
\end{align}}\end{align}
$$

where $(p,q,r)\in\mathbb Z^{3}$ with $p,q,r≠0\thinspace .$

---

For example, let $k=\dfrac 35$ we have :

$$
\begin{align}m&=\frac cb=\frac {16}{5}\\
n&=\frac ab=\frac {61}{5}\end{align}
$$

which leads to :

$$a=61k,\thinspace b=5k\thinspace ,c=16k$$

where $k\in\mathbb Z\thinspace .$

Comment: in case of interest:  in Mordell, Diophantine Equations, page 47, he proves that the primitive null vectors $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$   of an indefinite ternary quadratic form can be expressed with a finite collection of parametrizations of Pythagorean Triple type.

Comment: @WillJagy  Thank you for your reference. I'll gladly improve the answer if you have criticism that the general solution won't match the formulas I found .

Comment: well, with $\gcd(u,v)=1:$  and restrictions mod 2, 3, 5:  $a= 3 u^2 + 30uv- 5 v^2, $  $b= 3 u^2 -2uv- 5 v^2, $ $c= 3 u^2 + 5 v^2. $  With care, we can get primitive $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1.$  I do not believe your recipe gives any primitive triple with $c$  represented by $3 u^2 + 5 v^2$

Comment: I put what I meant as a CW  answer. A total of six parametrizations give all primitive $(a,b,c)$

Comment: @WillJagy  I'll make a minor edit when I'm available.  Based on the method I applied , no numbers should escape my answer .

Answer (score -1):

Posting what I meant: six Pythagorean Triple type parametrizations give all primitive integer  solutions  to $a^2 + 15 b^2 = 16 c^2$  For  example,  the one that gives $(1,1,1) $ is  capital letter B:
$$  a = u^2 - 30uv - 15 v^2 \; ; \; \;  b = u^2 +2uv - 15 v^2 \; ; \; \; c = u^2  + 15 v^2 \; ; \; \;   $$

Page 47 from Mordell, Diophantine Equations:

[image]

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
   a       b       c               u       v  
   1       1       1     B         1       0
   1       1       1     B        -1       0
   1       1       1       RAW   
   1      63      61     B         1      -2
   1      63      61     B        -1       2
   1      63      61       RAW   
   4       0       1     D         1       0
   4       0       1     D        -1       0
   4       0       1       RAW   
   4      32      31     D         0       1
   4      32      31     D         0      -1
   4      32      31     D         8      -1
   4      32      31     D        -8       1
   4      32      31       RAW   
   7       1       2     E         1       0
   7       1       2     E        -1       0
   7       1       2       RAW   
   7      33      32     E         1       1
   7      33      32     E        -1      -1
   7      33      32       RAW   
   7      95      92     E        11      -3
   7      95      92     E       -11       3
   7      95      92       RAW   
  11     221     214     F         8       7
  11     221     214     F        -8      -7
  11     221     214       RAW   
  11       3       4     F         1       0
  11       3       4     F        -1       0
  11       3       4       RAW   
  11      35      34     F         2      -1
  11      35      34     F        -2       1
  11      35      34       RAW   
  17      39      38     E         7      -2
  17      39      38     E        -7       2
  17      39      38       RAW   
  17       7       8     E         3      -1
  17       7       8     E        -3       1
  17       7       8       RAW   
  28      16      17     C         2       1
  28      16      17     C         2      -1
  28      16      17     C        -2       1
  28      16      17     C        -2      -1
  28      16      17       RAW   
  28      48      47     C         3       2
  28      48      47     C         3      -2
  28      48      47     C        -3       2
  28      48      47     C        -3      -2
  28      48      47       RAW   
  43      21      23     A         1       2
  43      21      23     A        -1      -2
  43      21      23       RAW   
  43      85      83     A         1       4
  43      85      83     A        -1      -4
  43      85      83       RAW   
  44     112     109     D         1      -2
  44     112     109     D        -1       2
  44     112     109     D        15      -2
  44     112     109     D       -15       2
  44     112     109       RAW   
  44      16      19     D         2      -1
  44      16      19     D        -2       1
  44      16      19     D         6      -1
  44      16      19     D        -6       1
  44      16      19       RAW   
  49     143     139     B         2      -3
  49     143     139     B        -2       3
  49     143     139       RAW   
  49      15      19     B         2      -1
  49      15      19     B        -2       1
  49      15      19       RAW   
  53      11      17     A         2      -1
  53      11      17     A        -2       1
  53      11      17       RAW   
  53     203     197     A         8      -1
  53     203     197     A        -8       1
  53     203     197       RAW   
  59      45      46     F         4       3
  59      45      46     F        -4      -3
  59      45      46       RAW   
  59      77      76     F         5       4
  59      77      76     F        -5      -4
  59      77      76       RAW   
  61       5      16     F         1       2
  61       5      16     F        -1      -2
  61       5      16       RAW   
  67       3      17     A         2       1
  67       3      17     A        -2      -1
  67       3      17       RAW   
  68      16      23     C         1       2
  68      16      23     C         1      -2
  68      16      23     C        -1       2
  68      16      23     C        -1      -2
  68      16      23       RAW   
  68     240     233     C         6       5
  68     240     233     C         6      -5
  68     240     233     C        -6       5
  68     240     233     C        -6      -5
  68     240     233       RAW   
  71       7      19     B         2       1
  71       7      19     B        -2      -1
  71       7      19       RAW   
  77     115     113     A         6      -1
  77     115     113     A        -6       1
  77     115     113       RAW   
  77      13      23     A         1      -2
  77      13      23     A        -1       2
  77      13      23       RAW   
  77      51      53     A         4      -1
  77      51      53     A        -4       1
  77      51      53       RAW   
 103     161     158     E         3       2
 103     161     158     E        -3      -2
 103     161     158       RAW   
 103      65      68     E         3       1
 103      65      68     E        -3      -1
 103      65      68       RAW   
 109      21      34     F         2       3
 109      21      34     F        -2      -3
 109      21      34       RAW   
 113     217     212     E         1       3
 113     217     212     E        -1      -3
 113     217     212       RAW   
 113      57      62     E         1      -2
 113      57      62     E        -1       2
 113      57      62       RAW   
 119     247     241     B         1      -4
 119     247     241     B        -1       4
 119     247     241       RAW   
 119      55      61     B         1       2
 119      55      61     B        -1      -2
 119      55      61       RAW   
 119       9      31     B         4       1
 119       9      31     B        -4      -1
 119       9      31       RAW   
 121       7      31     B         4      -1
 121       7      31     B        -4       1
 121       7      31       RAW   
 127      55      62     E         9      -2
 127      55      62     E        -9       2
 127      55      62       RAW   
 131     187     184     F         5      -2
 131     187     184     F        -5       2
 131     187     184       RAW   
 131      91      94     F         4      -1
 131      91      94     F        -4       1
 131      91      94       RAW   
 137      17      38     E         3      -2
 137      17      38     E        -3       2
 137      17      38       RAW   
 163      35      53     A         4       1
 163      35      53     A        -4      -1
 163      35      53       RAW   
 172      32      53     C         4       1
 172      32      53     C         4      -1
 172      32      53     C        -4       1
 172      32      53     C        -4      -1
 172      32      53       RAW   
 173      19      47     A         3      -2
 173      19      47     A        -3       2
 173      19      47       RAW   
 179      11      46     F         4       1
 179      11      46     F        -4      -1
 179      11      46       RAW   
 181      99     106     F         2      -3
 181      99     106     F        -2       3
 181      99     106       RAW   
 187     133     137     A         2       5
 187     133     137     A        -2      -5
 187     133     137       RAW   
 187       5      47     A         3       2
 187       5      47     A        -3      -2
 187       5      47       RAW   
 191      65      79     B         8       1
 191      65      79     B        -8      -1
 191      65      79       RAW   
 196      64      79     D        12      -1
 196      64      79     D       -12       1
 196      64      79     D         4       1
 196      64      79     D        -4      -1
 196      64      79       RAW   
 197      69      83     A         1      -4
 197      69      83     A        -1       4
 197      69      83       RAW   
 212      96     107     C         3       4
 212      96     107     C         3      -4
 212      96     107     C        -3       4
 212      96     107     C        -3      -4
 212      96     107       RAW   
 223     119     128     E        13      -3
 223     119     128     E       -13       3
 223     119     128       RAW   
 229      77      94     F         4       5
 229      77      94     F        -4      -5
 229      77      94       RAW   
 233     145     152     E         1      -3
 233     145     152     E        -1       3
 233     145     152       RAW   
 236      16      61     D         7      -2
 236      16      61     D        -7       2
 236      16      61     D         9      -2
 236      16      61     D        -9       2
 236      16      61       RAW   
 239     209     211     B        14       1
 239     209     211     B       -14      -1
 239     209     211       RAW   
 241     143     151     B         4      -3
 241     143     151     B        -4       3
 241     143     151       RAW   
 244     176     181     D        19      -2
 244     176     181     D       -19       2
 244     176     181     D         3       2
 244     176     181     D        -3      -2
 244     176     181       RAW   
   a       a       c               u       v
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
A:
a = 3*u*u + 30*u*v -5*v*v; 
b = 3*u*u -2*u*v -5*v*v; 
c = 3*u*u -0*u*v +5*v*v; 



B:
a = 1*u*u - 30*u*v -15*v*v; 
b = 1*u*u +2*u*v -15*v*v; 
c = 1*u*u -0*u*v +15*v*v; 


C:
a = 12*u*u + 0*u*v -20*v*v; 
b = 0*u*u + 8*u*v + 0*v*v; 
c = 3*u*u -0*u*v +5*v*v; 


D:
a = 4*u*u + 32*u*v +4*v*v; 
b = 0*u*u + 8*u*v + 32*v*v; 
c = 1*u*u +8*u*v +31*v*v; 


E:
a = 7*u*u + 20*u*v -20*v*v; 
b = 1*u*u + 12*u*v + 20*v*v; 
c = 2*u*u +10*u*v +20*v*v; 


F:
a = 11*u*u + 6*u*v -21*v*v; 
b = 3*u*u - 10*u*v + 3*v*v; 
c = 4*u*u -6*u*v +6*v*v;
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$